# Laravel 5 application can't connect MariaDB engine in docker container

Tags: docker, laravel-5, mariadb

I create a new Laravel 5 application in a docker container. I can access the home url and get the welcome message. I try create new routes and they are working too. Then I run a MariaDB docker container to link to the Laravel 5 application. Here is where the problems begin.
When I'm trying to run migrations in Laravel 5 with the following command:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'
```

My .env file are like this:

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_DATABASE=blog
    DB_USERNAME=blog
    DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

I know that these variables are used by Laravel to connect the data base because they exists in Laravel log file like this:

```
PDO->__construct(‘mysql:127….’, ‘blog’,  ‘123456’, Array)
```

The database engine is MariaDB and it is running in a docker container. This docker container exposes the port 3306 and is linked to the container that run Laravel. To link the container I use the following docker command:

```
docker run –i –t - - link mariadb:mysql miguelbgouveia/laravel:v3 /bin/bash
```

I also know that my MariaDB docker container is running with the correct configurations because I use a phpmyadmin docker container that is linked to it and I can connect with to the data base with success. I link the MariaDB container with the phpmyadmin container in the same manner that I link it to Laravel container (--link mariadb:mysql)

Why I can’t connect to the database? There is any configuration or php module to install that are missing?

Comment: Your dockers containers have different ip right?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Comment: Yes @RobertRozas, my containers have different IP's.

Comment: You have to create a user in your maria-db client, linked to the ip of your apache docker(i.e: apache docker ip: 192.168.1.112, then in your database docker create the user remoteuser@192.168.1.112)

Comment: It work @RobertRozas but my problem is that only know the IP of the MariaDB after the container start. I want to configure the containers before running them. It is this possible using links between containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all is very simple. If I use the mysql host in my environment variables it   just work without having to known the IP address of the MariaDB docker container.
The .env file goes like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=blog
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Now I can connect the MariaDB engine with success.